# IText CustomTagWorker setup for pdfHtml

Tags: itext, itext7

In what order are the methods of a CustomTagWorker instance called? (i.e. when is processContent called, when is processTagChild called, getElementResult?) A followup to this question is, how would one use the ProcessorContext arguments of these methods to add a page break in the pdf after the specific custom tag element? (I am running iText version 7.0.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A. If you're looking to implement page-breaks, pdfHTML 1.0.1 will support the page-break-after CSS property.

B. The easiest way for me to explain the calling sequence is to just show it. I made these two flowcharts when I was writing the custom tagworker examples, to help me figure out how the process worked.

These are accurate for 1.0.0, and conceptually accurate for 1.0.1 (additional functionality like page-break support and float layout require some additional steps).

[image: pdfHTML High level flow]

[image: Visit]